# Display data in ui-grid after making a rest call

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to display the data that i retrieved using rest call in a ui-grid table. When i bind the data to a scope variable and try to call it on the html page it gives a TYPEERROR: typeerror cannot read property "data" of undefined angularjs.
I guess it is not able to get the data and hence the error. Can anyone guide me as to what am i missing in the code below:

```
.controller("widgetCtrl", ["logger", "$scope", "$http", "widgetService", "localizationService",
        "gettextCatalog",
      function (logger, $scope, $http, widgetService, localizationService, gettextCatalog) {
        var myuid;
        var myrole;
        var locale = localizationService.getLocale();
        gettextCatalog.loadRemote("/dashboardplugins/B27F0520-86CF-1033-B9C8-005056A891F8/resources-locale_" +
         locale + ".json");
        logger.info("WidgetContoller started");
        $scope.gridOptions = {};
        /**
         * load function
         *
         */
        $scope.load = function () {
            widgetService.getData().then(function (response) {
                $scope.mydata = response;
                $scope.myrole = response.roles[0].split("/").pop();
                $scope.myuid =  $scope.myuid = response.meta["@href"].split("/").pop();
                $scope.gridOptions = {
                    excludeProperties: "__metadata",
                    data: [
                        {
                            id: $scope.myuid,
                            name: response.name,
                            role: $scope.myrole,
                            state: response.state
                        }
                    ],
                    columnDefs: [
                        {name: "ID", field: "id"},
                        {name: "Name", field: "name"},
                        {name: "role", field: "role"},
                        {name: "state", field: "state"}
                    ],
                    i18n: [
                    ]
                };
            });
        };
        $scope.load();
```

HtML page:

```
 <div ng-Controller="widgetCtrl">
    <h1>User Info</h1>
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

JSON data object:

```
    Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
config: Object
data: Object
auth-source: "DATABASE"
createdate: "2016-02-10T20:47:48.408Z"
creator: Object
meta: Object
moddate: "2016-02-10T20:47:48.408Z"
modifier: Object
name: "admin"
perms: Object
roles: Array[1]
state: "ACTIVE"
sys: false
tenant-id: 1
tenant-name: "default"
__proto__: Object
headers: (name)
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a reference to `$scope.gridOptions` outside of your `getData` function, so try setting `$scope.gridOptions = {};` somewhere above the `getData()` invocation. I think the *undefined* in your error refers to `$scope.gridOptions`, assuming what you posted above is the results of your `logger` function that verifies that you're getting data back from your service call.

Comment: Thanks! adding $scope.gridOptions = {}; helped in throwing the undefined data error away. But data is still not getting displayed. Do you think the inconsistent structure of the Json object could be the reason?

Comment: It's hard to know that without knowing what your returned JSON data looks like... what you show above is not JSON, but you should be able to access it with `response.data.data`. Can you either create a plunker or add the JSON data to your question? Regardless, you can massage the data into something that will show up once you have it on the client.

Comment: Yea i made some changes and the data is getting displayed. But i am not happy with my code. I usually don't prefer such hard coded approach.

Comment: Well, good, glad it's showing up now. Yeah, if your data objects aren't consistent, you don't have much choice but to do some massaging if you want ui-grid to be able to parse it.